# How to write conditional query in Solr?

Tags: php, search, solr, lucene

I am new to sonr and I have to write a conditional query. I just wanted to know can I write a query with multiple conditions.

I have four column and the query condition is something like following:-

Columns: name, address, city, state

Now if someone is searching by keyword "Romania" then the result should be based on following conditions:-

1. Search in name columns if keyword match with the name column then return the data and do not go for any further column.
2. If name column doesn't have that keyword then it will go to the address column and similar to the first step if result found then return the data otherwise it will go to next column.

It is a priority search in which the priory of columns to be used in search is predefined. If sonr provide any such functionality I want to use that instead of writing any fuzzy logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be to search all the columns you're talking about. Use `qf` to tell Solr which fields you want to query (when using the edismax query type):

```
qf=name address city
```

You can also give weights, so that a hit in the name column will be shown higher than a hit in the address column, which in turn will be shown higher than a hit in the city column:

```
qf=name^20 address^10 city
```

You might have to adjust the weights to get the search result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fq to search it like these:

```
fq=name:romania
```

or in the q

```
+name:"romania" or +address:"romania" or +city:"romania" or +state:"romania"
```

using OR is like in programming that if the first query is false, then move to the next one and to the next.